# Getting Python 2.x integer performance in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The following code performs better in Python 2.x than in Python 3.x

```
from time import time
n = 100000000
s = time()
while n > 0:
    n -= 1
print (time() - s)
```

In 2.7, it yields `7.84500002861` and `14.969856023788452` on 3.4 (on my machine of course).
This is due to Python 3.x removing special treatment for small int's and treating all integers similar to `long` in 2.x

Is there a way to get similar(or better) performance in Python 3.x for integers operations? Is there an `int` type similar to the one in 2.x?

Also, I don't get why this change was made, it hurts performance and I don't see much benefits.

Comment: Check out numpy for all your numeric needs. Here you're looking for numpy's `int32` or `int64` types, or more likely vectors of the same.

Comment: I would like to have those types without including a huge library like numpy. I considered it though.

Comment: You could use [PyPy](http://pypy.org) or `PyPy3` both of which execute this script in a fraction of a second. PyPy3 is actually *faster* than PyPy2. On my machine, about .4 seconds for your script.

Comment: *“I don't get why this change was made, it hurts performance”* – Because it’s not always about performance. Python is a lot about ease of programming allowing you to not care much about stuff and get things done instead.

Comment: If I have the option to use `PyPy` I would. I'm using Pygame, which PyPy doesn't support. `int` performance is fairly important since its used extensively

Comment: @poke, Why is the approach in 2.x not good enough? I suppose when the `int` gets large enough it turns into `long`, but the change of type is really not a problem thanks to duck typing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Also, I don't get why this change was made, it hurts performance and I don't see much benefits.

Python is not a number crunching language, and it's not about the absolute best performance.  It's about simplicity, clarity, and correctness.  The extra bit of speed was not great enough to justify the maintenance burden of two different integer types for the folks who actually develop and maintain Python.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing one hundred million subtractions in around ten seconds.  That's ten per microsecond, or a hundred sixty thousand per frame.

Somehow I doubt this is actually your bottleneck.  Have you measured your actual code?  What made you decide to measure and blame int performance specifically?

For what it's worth I get similar results to razpeitia: about half the difference in Python 3 is due to the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Stop assuming stuff before actually profiling the code.

What it's expensive is the comparison, no the addition or subtraction.

It's insanely faster with a different comparison:

```
from time import time
n = 100000000
s = time()
while n:
    n -= 1
print (time() - s)
```

Comparisons in python has been always expensive.

Time:
Python 2.7: With comparison
7.28864598274

Python 3.4: With comparison
13.904897212982178

Python 2.7: Without comparison
7.14143395424

Python 3.4: Without comparison
9.274619102478027

Comment: Perhaps you could share your numbers with and without the change?  For Pythons 2 and 3?

Comment: Comparison performance shouldn't be ignored. I did make the assumption though. Thanks for the insight :)